# Как сделать видео с заглушкой?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня вот так

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но видео с ютуба почему то не воспроизводятся.

```
<section class="videoplay">
<div class="video1">
    <div class="video1-play" onclick="videoplay(this);"></div>
</div>
```

```
.videoplay
.video1 
width: 1300px
height: 490px
position: relative
border: 1px solid #000
background: url('../img/video.png')  0% 0% / cover
&-play 
  background-image: url('../img/play.png')
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-size: cover
  height: 50px
  width: 50px
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  margin-left: -45px
  margin-top: -30px
  position: absolute
  border-radius: 21px
  background-position: 50% 50%
  cursor: pointer
  &:hover 
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 #000
```

Comment: Вы в курсе что у вас синтаксис css некорректный и нужно еще less подключать? А где ссылка на урл видео?

Comment: @coder675 у меня sass. куда именно нужно подключить урл видео?

Comment: в ютуб iframe же

Comment: @MaximLensky могли бы вы пример показать? а то я так не разберусь никогда в этом(

Comment: Видео можно вставить вот так <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/klYTEMiATZw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> но тогда у вас не будет доступа к функциям видео. Если вы хотите сделать свою картинку поверх видео видео, то его надо подключать чере API используя js. И при клике на свою кнопку нужно скрывать свою картинку с кнопкой, а при остановке видео показывать. Это сложновать сделать.

Comment: вам надо обязательно с youtube видос взять ? почему своё видео нельзя ?

Comment: @MaximLensky не обязательно. главное принцип работал, который описала

Answer (score 0):

Само видео я скачал с youtube маленький футаж

> Функция которые запускает видео `play();`
>
> Функция которая видео ставит на паузу `pause();`
>
> Вот акцент на этом: `video.play();` и на этом `video.pause()`;

Пример кода в сниппете но так как я уверен что видео не будет здесь работать то ссылку на 100% рабочим кодом в zip архиве прикладываю [скачать пример рабочего кода](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2fPa/4cs5u1dMo)

> Этот пример работает в песочнице :
>   https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OeMYoo
>
> но надо чуть чуть подождать что бы видео загрузилось

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#video");
var back = document.querySelector("#back");


document.querySelector("#play").onclick = function (){
  document.querySelector("#pause").style.display = 'inline-block';
  this.style.display = 'none';
  back.style.display = 'none';
  video.play();
}


document.querySelector("#pause").onclick = function (){
  document.querySelector("#play").style.display = 'inline-block';
  this.style.display = 'none';
  back.style.display = 'block';
  video.pause();
}
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding: 0; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
#trailer.overlay { 
 display: block; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 position: relative;
}
#video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

#trailer  video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 min-width: 100%; 
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; 
 height: auto;
}
.panel{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.panel .fab,
.panel .fas{
 font-size:60px;
 color:#fff;
 z-index:101;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 top:50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);

}
.panel .fas{
    display: none;
}
.panel .fab:hover,
.panel .fas:hover{
 color: lightblue;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.panel .overlay{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index: 100;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
<section id="trailer" class="overlay">

  <video width="100%" height="auto" id="video" muted="">
    <!--source src="futage4K.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'-->
    <source src="http://lensky.0fees.us/sourse/4K%20Happy%20Blue%20Flare%20Void%20Royalty%20Free%20Background%20Animation.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>    

<div class="panel">
 <div id="back" class="overlay"></div>
 <i id="play" class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
 <i id="pause" class="fas fa-pause"></i>
</div>

 </section>
```

Comment: замечательно! это то,  что нужно. но у меня не работает видео. я скачала и ничего.

Comment: @VictoriaPisareva действительно видео не загружается в codepen, скачайте и замените ссылку на видео в формате mp4

Comment: я пока сделала iframe